# Placing divs dynamically onto page

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-3

I am currently working on placing two divs below a header image but am having issues with it.  Here is a picture of what I want it to look like.

[image]

As you can see, I managed to get the Office with a combo box, and a link to the right hand edge of the header image.  The two are wrapped up in divs to separate them.  Below is the html.

```
<div style="width: 1000px; background-position:center;">
                <div id="divOfficeWrapper" style="float:right">
                    <% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/OfficeSelector.ascx"); %>
                </div>
                <div style="float: right; margin-right: -335px;">
                    <%
                        Html.DevExpress().HyperLink(hpr =>
                            {
                                hpr.Name = "hprGreetings";
                                hpr.NavigateUrl = Url.Action("Index", "UserProfile", new { Area = "mySCCVUE" });
                                hpr.Properties.Text = string.Format("Welcome, {0}", Session["UserFullName"]);
                                hpr.Style.Add("font-style", "italic");
                                hpr.Style.Add("font-weight", "bold");
                                hpr.Style.Add("font-size", "9pt");
                                hpr.Style.Add("color", "white");
                                hpr.Style.Add("font-family", "Helvetica");
                                hpr.Style.Add("text-decoration", "underline");
                            }).Render();    
                     %>                    
                </div>
            </div>
```

The problem is obviously browser size.  I modeled this to be off my development box, however, when I demoed, the divs containing office and the link moved towards the center.  One piece of info I learned is the header image is 1000px in width.

I'm somewhat at a loss on how to get them to size correctly and would appreciate any direction.

Comment: Remove the `margin` from the child divs, and place the wrapper div` at the center of the page using `margin-left: 0 auto;`

Comment: I tried that already and it just moves the link to the left side of the combo box.